# Ctrl-A not working in vim command line mode

Tags: vim

In vim command mode, while i am typing a really long search and replace command, how do i go to the beginning of the line?

`Ctrl+e` and `Ctrl+w` are working. But when i press `Ctrl+a` it just prints `^A`.

Is there any other way to jump to the beginning of the line?

Comment: It's the same as in pretty much every text input widget in every program written with every UI toolkit on every platform: `<Home>`.

Comment: i dont have <Home> on my laptop keyboard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>Home</kbd> will jump the cursor to the beginning of the line in command-line mode.

See `:help c_Home`.

Adding

```
cnoremap <C-A> <Home>
```

to your `.vimrc` will let you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You could try these mappings, taken from the longer list of tcsh-style key bindings documented in `:help tcsh-style`:

```
:cnoremap <C-A> <Home>
:cnoremap <C-F> <Right>
:cnoremap <C-B> <Left>
```